# when nothing selected from the spinner it shows alert message in android

Tags: android, spinner, android-alertdialog

when nothing selected from the spinner it shows alert message in android

Comment: no value is selected from the spinner at that time while clicking the button it shows some alert messeges

Comment: What the button do, what is the text of the message, what logcat shows? Ask more informative questions, and answers will follow immediately!

Answer (score 1):

First refer this article already provided on the Android site itself: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html ,

And find the below method:

```
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
       // display your alert box
    }
```

Comment: i had one button called "add",without selecting value from the spinner,we click that add button it will shows alert messege.